Monte-Carlo Calculation of correlations functions in QFT using the Euclidean action
I'm trying to understand conceptually how correlation functions in QFT can be calculated using Monte-Carlo methods. The procedure is described in general terms e.g. here: basically it builds on the fact that with the Euclidean action defined by the transformation $t \to it$, the path integral can be viewed as a classical probability distribution over field configurations, such that for example
$$ G_E(x-y)=\langle 0 | \phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle_E =  \frac{ \displaystyle\int e^{-S_E} \phi(x) \phi(y)\, D\phi} {\displaystyle\int e^{-S_E}\, D\phi}. $$
Is just the statistical expectation of $\phi(x)\phi(y)$ under the distribution $e^{-S_E}$. Now my understanding is that to get back to the actual correlation function, we need to evaluate $G_E(x-y)$ at imaginary time, i.e.
$$ G(\vec x , t) = G_E(\vec x, -it)$$
or in other words analytically continue $G_E(\vec x, t)$ (which is real, for a real scalar field) to the complex plane.
But when using Monte-Carlo to calculate a statistical average for $\langle 0 | \phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle_E$, we are just getting a number for each value of $x$ and $y$, not an analytical function. So how can this last step be done?

Analytically continuing the MC data from imaginary  to real time is very challenging. That is why most MC calculations aim at extracting information, such as ground state energies, order parameters, and masses that, being time idependent, do not require this step.  Nonetheless there are strategies, and this is a very active area of research.
One strategy is to use information, such as unitarity or something like that, to constrain the functional form of the correlator as a parameterized function. The MC data is then used to estmate the parameters. Other methods incude variations on maximal entropy statistsics.

Thanks. Does that mean, in the context of the question, that we can only use this method to calculate correlation functions at equal times ?

Yes. I'd say that that is possible.
